# Sending AT commands in Arduino Code

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, signal-strength

Im using an HC 05 bluetooth module for tracking Signal strength of my device.
For that signal strength im using the AT command RSSI. But i want my code to request the RSSI value continuously and track accordingly. Is there any way to send AT commands via normal Arduino code instead of command window or serial command. Please help!

Comment: How do you send AT commands through serial monitor? Ok, in exactly the same way you can send them through the arduino interface... I think you should tie the KEY pin to ground, then just send the data through the serial interface..

Comment: Use the Serial Libary: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial